# Function to concatenate two string who write to the begin of this buffer?

Tags: c++, concatenation

We have StringCchCat function in Win32Api,

> Concatenates one string to another string. The size of the destination
>   buffer is provided to the function to ensure that StringCchCat does
>   not write past the end of this buffer.

Ok so ..

```
StringCchCat(dirWPath, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));
```

I ll get : dirWPath + "\\*"

I look for get a :"\\*"  + dirWPath

Anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the wildcard first:

```
char str1[MAX_PATH] = "\\*";
StringCchCat(str1, MAX_PATH, dirWPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string first = dirWPath, second = "\\*";
std::string result = second + first;
```